# MKMapView Popup Bubble: show new xib on click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, annotations, mkmapview

How do I load a new xib when my user taps on the popup bubble on an MkMapView?

I've tried scouring the internet, but can't find a solution to this problem.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control` method you should create a new VC with your xib and push it to the navigation controller or display it however you want.
For example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
     NewViewController* vc = [[[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newXib" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

You can find a lot of tutorials how to create and display new Views, you should start scouring harder. ;)

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your reply. I just could not find this info anywhere on the web. How do I know which marker was clicked?

Comment: OK, I got it now...  MapAnnotations *annotation = view.annotation;
    NSLog(@"%@",annotation.title); Thanks so much for your help.